# Web page hosted using firebase only returns Internal Server Error

Tags: node.js, firebase

[Web page where the error occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YXLu.png)

When I tested using "firebase serve" there's no error or bug at all.
But after hosting using "firebase deploy" it appears like above in the single page.
I checked function logs but there's no error message.
Where can I find the reason?

Comment: I resolve this problem! I used "res.render" to render ejs. It seems that makes problem.
I replaced the code with fs.readFile to render html.